# How to Auto Focus on next input box with jeasyui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a problem setting focus in the next textbox am using the easy UI plugin. I know there is an option do this with MaskedBox

```
<input class="easyui-maskedbox" mask="(999) 999-9999" style="width:100%">
```

but I want to do this with the easyui-textbox can anyone help me do this functionally.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="otp-textbox">
    <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox" />
    <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox" />
    <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox" />
</div>
```

**Generate the HTML in DOM**

```
<div class="otp-textbox">
        <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox textbox-f" style="display: none;">
        <span class="textbox">
            <input id="_easyui_textbox_input20" type="text" class="textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt"
                autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="" maxlength="1"
                style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 28px; line-height: 28px; width: 182.4px;">
                <input type="hidden" class="textbox-value" value="">
            </span>
        <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox textbox-f" style="display: none;">
        <span class="textbox">
            <input id="_easyui_textbox_input21" type="text" class="textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt"
                autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="" maxlength="1"
                style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 28px; line-height: 28px; width: 182.4px;">
                <input type="hidden" class="textbox-value" value="">
            </span>
        <input type="text" class="easyui-textbox textbox-f" style="display: none;">
            <span class="textbox">
                <input id="_easyui_textbox_input22" type="text" class="textbox-text validatebox-text textbox-prompt"
                autocomplete="off" tabindex="" placeholder="" maxlength="1"
                style="margin: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 28px; line-height: 28px; width: 182.4px;">
                <input type="hidden" class="textbox-value" value="">
        </span>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".otp-textbox .textbox").find('input.textbox-text').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('maxlength', 1);
    $(this).on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
            $(this).next().focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
```

Instad of this:

```
$(this).next().focus();
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it this but doesn't work. When I alert this will give a [object Object]  and int he consoles this will give me. prevObject: w.fn.init [input#_easyui_textbox_input20.textbox-text.validatebox-text]